# Create and Fill HSQLDB from Script

Tags: command-line, hsqldb

I have the following problem with my HSQLDB. I need to populate very often the whole database with new testdata and new database schema. so i delete the file, and create a new database.

Now i see that i can do this via commandline and tried:

```
java -cp ~/bin/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager --url 'jdbc:hsqldb:file:database/tsc.hsqldb' --user 'sa' --script sql/database.sql
```

which does not work really good, because it only opens the DatabaseManager with the script loaded. i still need to execute by hand. This is very bad, because i have two databases (test and livedata) and therefore 3 scripts which needs to be executed on the database.
Is there any Option to execute the script directly and then close the manager? 
I ask because i cant find any good documentation on the hsqldb website and also no option when i try `--help`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SqlTool to execute an SQL script against the database. See:

http://hsqldb.sourceforge.net/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html